# HP f1905 Display is shifted too low. Task bar is lost. How do I move it upward?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do I move the display upward a half inch? I tried the settings, resolution, task bar location.

Comment: Try using the "Auto Configuration" option on the monitor as detailed [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00032234#AbT3). Alternatively, you can manually adjust the image position using "Image Control".

Answer (score 0):

Go to OSD Settings via the control buttons on your monitor and navigate to some settings like **Height Position** most likely to find beneath the **Image Settings** tab.
Normally the ideal height is 50 but that my be different for your case.

If your monitor has an **Auto** button, you may try that first.